# How to apply Distinct Query in OrientDB?

Tags: orientdb, oriento

I want use Distinct Query in OrientDb. Any one have idea about that how to apply that but i want Distinct Query Builder.

[Oriento Query](https://github.com/codemix/oriento)

I know that : `SELECT DISTINCT(name) FROM City`

but I want something like that Query Builder : `db.select().distinct(name).from(City)`

```
//Right Select Query Builder
db.select().from('City').where({status: 'true'}).all()
```

AND

how to apply object in below Query ?

```
  var abc = {Country : 'India'};
  'SELECT DISTINCT(name) FROM City where' + abc ;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You probably want something like

`db.select('distinct(name)').from('City').column('name').all()`